# {exp:assets:files} does not output anything

Tags: pixelandtonic, assets

Since I updated my EE installation from 2.5.5 to 2.6.0 the {exp:assets:files}-tag pair does not output anything anymore. I have also updated Assets to 2.1.1. Also {exp:assets:total_files} returns zero. The {exp:assets:folders}-tag pair works fine. I have also reindexed all files.

My template code looks like this:

```
<ul class="unstyled">
    {exp:assets:folders parent_folder="{filedir_5}"}
        <li><i class="icon-folder-open"></i> {folder_name}</a>
            {if total_subfolders}
                <ul class="unstyled" style="margin-left: 25px;">
                    {subfolders}
                </ul>
            {/if}
            <ul class="unstyled" style="margin-left: 25px;">
                {exp:assets:files folder_id="{folder_id}"}
                    <li><i class="icon-file"></i> <a href="/{exp:link_vault:download_link file_path='../../../../{server_path}' url_only='true' action_only='true' }">{if title != ""}{title}{if:else}{filename}{/if} ({size})</a></li>
                {/exp:assets:files}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {/exp:assets:folders}
</ul>
```

I am showing a whole file hierarchy of a file directory above the web root (therefore link-vault-addon usage). The folder are outputted correctly but no files are shown. I have also tried your example usage from the docs:

```
{exp:assets:folders recursive="yes"}
<h3>{folder_name}</h3>
<ul>
    {exp:assets:files folder_id="{folder_id}"}
        <li><a href="{url:huge}" target="_blank">{if title != ""}{title}{if:else}{filename}{/if}</a></li>
    {/exp:assets:files}
</ul>
{/exp:assets:folders}
```

But this also only outputs all folders but no files.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you re-indexed at all?

Comment: Hey yoursort - on top of re-indexing - please check that /system/expressionengine/cache is set to 777 permissions, and that your file upload directories also are.  Can you also post your full template code in your original post? I see the link, but I'd like to see exactly what you are testing with.

Comment: Yes, the permissions are fine. See the template code in the question.

Comment: Hey yoursort - there is currently a bug with the parent_folder parameter stopping any output. I've submitted that to our devs.  I cna also reproduce that the sample code from the docs does not work and have submitted that as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the long wait - we've isolated the bug and fixed it - the fix will be included in the next release.

For a hot-fix, open the third_party/assets/libraries/assets_lib file, locate the get_files_in_folder method and add this at the very beginning of this method:

```
if (is_array($file_ids))
{
  $file_ids = array_filter($file_ids);
}
```

That should fix your thing!